# Shortcode To Display Post Custom Field Value in Post Title, Post Content

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, title

I want to create a shortcode that pulls value from a custom field of a post and parses that value on Post title, post content.

So if the custom field value is **Icecream** for Post 1.

On the admin side the post title will be **Favorite [geo_name]**, it will be displayed as **Favorite Icecream**.

Here is my code so far:

```
function geo_name_function( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'geo_name' );

    return get_post_meta( $atts['post_id'], 'field_name', true );
}

add_shortcode('geo_name', 'geo_name_function');

add_filter( 'the_title', function( $geo_name_function ) {
    return do_shortcode( $geo_name_function );
});
```

I keep having one issue.

If Recent Posts Widget is on one of the posts it displays the same value for all post titles.

For example:

Article 1

[geo name] value = Geo 1

Admin title: [geo_name] title Rendered title: Geo 1 title

Article 2

[geo name] value = Geo 2

Admin title: [geo_name] title Rendered title: Geo 2 title

If I am on an Article 1 page my Recent Post Widget looks like:

Recent Posts

Geo 1 title -> url to article 1

Geo 1 title -> url to article 2

If I am on an Article 2 page my Recent Post Widget looks like:

Recent Posts

Geo 2 title -> url to article 1

Geo 2 title -> url to article 2

My PHP knowledge is very limited, Please assist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_title` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/) takes two parameters, one of them is the ID of the post for which it was called. Something like that should work.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'se385007_title_filter', 20, 2 );
function se385007_title_filter( $title, $post_id ) 
{
    $new_title = str_replace( "[geo_name]", "[geo_name post_id=$post_id]", $title );
    return do_shortcode( $new_title );
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's expected. `get_the_ID()` returns `post_ID` from main query, and in a single page will return `post_ID` for that page. The way you filter post title affects all post title that'll be rendered in a page regardless of their actual `post_ID`. Since the problem is in a widget, you need to get the ID from its query (not main one).

I'd try to use the following instead (untested):

```
function geo_name_function( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => get_queried_object_id(),
    ), $atts, 'geo_name' );

    return get_post_meta( $atts['post_id'], 'field_name', true );

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input, I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work. Do you have other suggestions?